# Folland Chapter 7, Exercise 13

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

**Chapter 7 Exercise 13** of Folland's "Real Analysis" reads

> Let $X=\mathbb R\times \mathbb R_d$ where $\mathbb R_d$ denotes the discrete topology. Let $f$ be a function on $X$ and define a positive linear functional on $C_c(X)$ by
> $$I(f)=\sum_{y\in \mathbb R}\int f(x,y)\text{ d}x$$
> and let $\mu$ be the associated Radon measure on $X$.
> Let $A=\left(\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}\right)\times \mathbb R_d$ and $\phi (x,y)=|x|$. Then the measures
> $$\mu_A(E)=\mu(A\cap E)$$
> and
> $$\nu(E)=\int_E \phi \text{ d}\mu$$
> are not Radon measures.

This uses the setting of Exercise 12 where I have proved the following results-

1. Defining $f^\textbf{y}=f(x,\textbf{y})$, we have $f\in C_c(X)$ iff $f^y\in C_c(\mathbb R)$ for all $y$ and $f^y=0$ for all but finitely many $y$.
2. Defining $E^y=\{x: (x,y)\in E\}$, we have $\mu(E)=\infty$ for any $E$ such that $E^y\neq \emptyset$ for uncountably many $y$.
3. Let $E=\{0\}\times \mathbb R_d$. Then $\mu(E)=\infty$ but $\mu(K)=0$ for all compact $K\subset E$.

The present question provides an explanation for the fact that $\sigma$-finiteness in [Exercise 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9glh8Yo6bo) and $\phi\in L^1(\mu)$ in [Exercise 8](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3220384/943723) cannot be dropped. So, I guess that the fact that $A$ is not $\sigma$-finite needs to be somehow used.

However, I couldn't make much progress on the given problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem $2.17$, Rudin's RCA (Dictionary Order Topology)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155744/problem-2-17-rudins-rca-dictionary-order-topology)

Comment: @OliverDíaz I think what you linked to is Folland Ex 12 (which I have solved), and what I posted is Ex 13...

Answer (score 2):

In the [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4156330/121671) I referred in my comment, it is shown that for any Lebesgue measurable set $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $\mu(B\times \{y\} )=\lambda(B)$. Then, the  usual argument of approximating functions by simple functions shows that for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$ fixed and any nonnegative (or bounded) measurable function $f:(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{\{y\}}f(x)\,\mu(dx,dy)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\,dx$$
In particular,
$$\nu(B\times\{y\})=\int_B|x|\,dx$$

- For $\mu_A$ notice that if $E=\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}_d$, $\mu_A(E)=0$ while for any open set $G$ containing $E$, $\mu_A(E)=\infty$.
- For $\nu$, also $\nu(E)=0$ but for any open set $G$ containing $E$, $\nu(G)=\infty$.

The argument is similar for both $\mu_A$ and $\nu$ and it is described is the solution to the aforemetioned [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4155744/121671): Any open set $G$ containing $E$ has a set of the form $U=\bigcup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}(-a_y,a_y)\times\{y\}$. There is $n_o\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $E_{n_0}=\{y: a_u>\frac{1}{n_0}\}$ is uncountable. Then,
\begin{align}
\nu(G)&\geq\nu(U)\geq\sup_{J\subset E_{n_0}}\nu((-a_y,a_y)\times\{y\})=\sup_{J\subset E_{n_0}}\int^{a_y}_{-a_y}|y|\,dy=\infty\\
\mu_A(G)&\geq\mu_A(U)\geq \sup_{J\subset E_{n_0}}\mu_A((-a_y,a_y)\times\{y\})=\sup_{J\subset E_{n_0}}2a_x=\infty
\end{align}
where the sup is over all finite subsets $J$ of $E_{n_0}$.